# Dolphin not showing pdf or video previews

Tags: dolphin, previews

Kubuntu 18.04.2. I am pretty sure I have all the right settings activated. PDFs are previewed in folder icons:

[image]

But when I open the folders there is no PDF preview:

[image]

Comment: On my system, which is also Kubuntu 18.04, I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSr9p.png

Comment: This is how the folder looks: [Link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xf7QJkBPyxu9pIjL11fOgdtEz6A6__mo) and this is inside the folder [Link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d4rM1BnZHf8zLRIC71WqUd7VPePu_RAX)

Comment: @DK Bose That's exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To enable previews in both the folder and in files, open Dolphin's settings > Configure Dolphin > General tab > Previews. In there, select "Folders" as well as whichever file type you wish to view previews for.

In the image below, I have Dolphin opened in dual-pane mode.

- In the left window, I've boxed the **PDFs** folder.
- In the right window, you can see previews of individual files.
- The window on top is Dolphin's settings to enable the previews you want. Both *Folders* **and** *Postscript, PDF and DVI files* are selected.
- Note that there are sliders at the bottom of each pane for you to adjust the icon size for optimal viewing.

[image: Dolphin showing previews of folders and individual files]

Comment: Hi, I have already done that, checked the box for folders, PDFs and other files. The funny thing is that the PDFs show in the folders and image files preview perfectly. It is just PDF and movie files that don't show.

Comment: This is what it looks like: ![Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KJJwJjbzKrY_13LNJSJfAhtAibvL3hwv).

Comment: Could you explain how to access the module you've shown above? It refers to "Configure general file manager settings". Where can that be found?

Comment: Are you actually using Kubuntu 18.04.2? Have you tried using Dolphin's interface? Dolphin has "Dolphin Preferences -- Dolphin" whereas you have "Configure general file manager settings". Please clarify so that neither of us waste our time!

Comment: Now that did the trick! I was accessing Dolphin settings via "General File Manager" settings. Funnily enough it had the exact same options. Sorry for taking your time and thank you very much!